# Is there a direct parallel to actual social prejudices for each color in "The War Between the Classes"?

Tags: symbolism, the-war-between-the-classes, gloria-d-miklowitz

In *The War Between the Classes*, the class sets up four levels of classes: Blue, the highest class; Dark Green, the lower high class; Light Green, the higher low class; and Orange, the lowest of the low.

Is there a direct parallel to actual social prejudices for each color? E.g., Orange representing African Americans? Or Blue representing the white population?

Can we draw a parallel for each color?